# TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string ngx-print\fesm2020\ngx-print.mjs

Tags: java, node.js, angular

My node version is 16.16.0. while I'm trying to do ng serve it gives me this trace.

> /node_modules/ngx-print/fesm2020/ngx-print.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
> TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\TRANS23-LAP-RA1\Documents\GitHub\NYMTC-Angular\nymtc-web\node_modules\ngx-print\fesm2020\ngx-print.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 15.0.4, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
> Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
> 162 | }
> 163 | NgxPrintDirective.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.0.4", ngImport: i0, type: NgxPrintDirective, deps: [], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Directive });
> 164 | NgxPrintDirective.ɵdir = i0.ɵɵngDeclareDirective({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "15.0.4", type: NgxPrintDirective, selector: "button[ngxPrint]", inputs: { previewOnly: "previ
> ewOnly", printSectionId: "printSectionId", printTitle: "printTitle", useExistingCss: "useExistingCss", printDelay: "printDelay", printStyle: "printStyle", styleSheetFile: "styleSheetFile" }, host: { listeners: { "click": "print()" } }, ngImport: i0 });
> 167 |             args: [{'
> at run (C:\Users\TRANS23-LAP-RA1\Documents\GitHub\NYMTC-Angular\nymtc-web\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:27:15)
> at transform.next ()
> at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\TRANS23-LAP-RA1\Documents\GitHub\NYMTC-Angular\nymtc-web\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
> at C:\Users\TRANS23-LAP-RA1\Documents\GitHub\NYMTC-Angular\nymtc-web\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40
> 93     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<NgxPrintDirective, "button[ngxPrint]", never, { "previewOnly": "previewOnly"; "printSectionId": "printSectionId"; "printTitle": "printTitle"; "useExistingCss": "useExistingCss"; "printDelay": "printDelay"; "printStyle": "printStyle"; "styleSheetFile": "styleSheetFile"; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;

I tried downgrading and upgrading versions which didn't work! I really need help in this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error indicates that your Angular version is out of date. Do you have Angular 14.0.0 or newer installed?

Comment: Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.16) is greater than your local version (12.0.5). The local Angular CLI version is used.
Looks like this is my version

Answer (score 0):

Yuo are getting this error because your dependencies can only run on Angular 14 or newer. Therefore, you need to upgrade your application (or remove the dependencies).

This is not about updating node, but Angular.

You can check in detail how to upgrade your Angular application here:
https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-14.0